# jmp 0x0008:0x0000 vs jmp 0x00000008:0x00000000 in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Is there any difference between them? I am using this code to jump from real mode to protected mode. the second one works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the length of the instruction (due to the longer absolute address encoded in it and any possibly required instruction prefixes) there's no difference between the two whatsoever.

The two versions of the instruction behave identically.

You're not restricted to using only the shorter version in 16-bit mode or only the longer version in 32-bit mode. As long as the address is valid (per the relevant segment descriptor in the GDT and then the underlying page tables, if any), the jump will just work.

**UPDATE**: Actually (found by trial and error:), you want to request the proper operand size specifically if the offset doesn't fit into 16 bits.

Sample code:

```
bits 16
jmp 8:0
jmp dword 8:0
jmp 8:0x12345678 ; warning: jmpabs.asm:4: warning: word data exceeds bounds
bits 32
jmp 8:0
jmp word 8:0
jmp 8:0x1234
```

Assembled as `nasm -f bin -l jmpabs.lst jmpabs.asm -o jmpabs.bin` produces the following listing file:

```
 1                                  bits 16
 2 00000000 EA00000800              jmp 8:0
 3 00000005 66EA000000000800        jmp dword 8:0
 4 0000000D EA78560800              jmp 8:0x12345678
 5          ******************       warning: word data exceeds bounds
 6                                  bits 32
 7 00000012 EA000000000800          jmp 8:0
 8 00000019 66EA00000800            jmp word 8:0
 9 0000001F EA341200000800          jmp 8:0x1234
```

Comment: they are same no matter 16-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: I can compile `JMP 0x00000008:0x00000000` no warning, does it mean I complie in 32-bit mode by default? i use: `nasm -f bin boot.s -o boot.bin`

Comment: I don't remember what the default value of `bits` is in NASM. You can compile `JMP 0x00000008:0x00000000` in both modes and you will get different instruction lengths as shown in the listing file above. NASM won't issue any warning here, because in either mode there's no offset truncation unlike in the case `jmp 8:0x12345678`.

Comment: i think jmp 8:0x12345678 is same as jmp 0x00000008:0x12345678, is it?

Comment: Correct. Btw, segment selectors are always 16-bit.

Comment: why you write "jmp 8:0x1234" at the last code, is it "jmp 8:0x12345678"?

Comment: so 16-bit "jmp dword 0x0008:0x0000" is equal to 32-bit "jmp 0x0008:0x00000000"？but the machine code are: 66EA000000000800 and EA000000000800. when i use it for real-mode to protect-mode, which is right?

Comment: If you are asking about the deifference at the source code level, NASM doesn't care about the meaningless zeroes. If you are asking about the differently encoded versions of the same instruction, there isn't much of a practical difference other than the instruction length. I think there's been enough information provided to answer the question(s).

Comment: I told you already, you can use jmp sel16:ofs16 in 16-bit and 32-bit modes and you can use jmp sel16:ofs32 in 16-bit and 32-bit modes.

Comment: Isn't that just because NASM optimizes operand's sizes ? http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.12.02/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.22

Answer (score 0):

At least for me both work and produce identical opcodes.

From `ndisasm -b 32`:

```
000000B5  EA000000000800    jmp dword 0x8:0x0
000000BC  EA000000000800    jmp dword 0x8:0x0
```

Leading zeros don't change change numeric value, and this is same for all numeral systems, be it binary, decimal or hexadecimal.

Comment: thanks. i want to know what is the difference of NASM deal with them.

Comment: I tested and both produce identical opcode using `nasm -f elf32`. So there's no difference.

Comment: maybe they are different in 16 or 32 bits? could you try nasm -f elf16?

Comment: @sangwf At least my `nasm` doesn't have `-f elf16`. There is `-f elf64`, `-f elf32` and finally `-f elf`, that is short name for `elf32`. You can check the available formats by running `nasm -hf`.